# Dropdownlist with IEnumerable Data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

My model looks like this

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductTypes { get; set; }

    public ProductContent()
    {
        productxEntities db = new productxEntities();

        ProductTypes = db.ProductCodes.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.product_type.ToString(),
            Text = c.code.ToString()
        });



    }
```

when i try to use it for `DropDownList` I get a error saying casting is wrong... what is the correct way of populating DDL using list from DB in MVC3 Razor C#, i have a tightly coupled view for this model type.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProductTypes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) Model.ProductTypes)
```

this is the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ProductContent productViewModel = new ProductContent();
        return PartialView("../PartialViews/NewProduct", productViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: **What error do you get?** What is the _exact_ text of the error?

Comment: Putting that logic into your model isn't a good idea. It should be somewhere else. You should also post your controller's code to see how the Action is returning the model.

Comment: when posting the error i found that the error was due to not using using System.Web.Mvc for selecte itemlist but now i have a new error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be calling `ToList` somewhere in your EF query. Otherwise you are returning a Queryable directly to your View.

Possibly like this:

```
public ProductContent()
{
    productxEntities db = new productxEntities();

    ProductTypes = db.ProductCodes.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.product_type.ToString(),
        Text = c.code.ToString()
    });
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment though; I'd discourage this kind of code in a constructor of a Model. Someone else should be assigning it to the Model.

You should then be able to remove your cast in your View.

Comment: i have this new error now
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Minor: You probably want `ToList()` after your `Select` or it'll pull the whole table instead of just the two columns you need.

Comment: you mean 
  ProductTypes = db.ProductCodes.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.product_type.ToString(),
        Text = c.code.ToString()
    }).ToLIst();

Comment: @Natasha - almost. Without the first ToList: `db.ProductCodes.Select(blah).ToList();`

Comment: @user122211: You'd have to do ..`Select(columns).ToList().Select(new SelectListItem)` EF won't know how to select a SelectListItem.

Comment: You can also replace the first `ToList` call with `AsEnumerable`; this shows the intent without forcing an early iteration.

Comment: Obviously it's "System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem" and "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem", but not IQueryable and IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem is that the types `System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem` and `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` are not assignable.

It's likely that there are different namespace imports in the controller to the view. You need to be explicit in this case: either the model needs to use `new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem(...)` or the view needs to cast to `(IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>)`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this is relavent. The problem was trying to return an IQueryable, which won't work because The DB connection might be closed once it tries to enumerate; and it wasn't a valid cast.

Comment: @vcsjones the error in the question was an invalid cast, not the IQueryable; that's what I addressed. Your advice on the IQueryable was useful and correct, as it pointed out a possible point of pain (connection closed, multiple query executions, etc).